# Using git clone without direct internet connection

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, git

I have a new (to me) Dell desktop, on which I have successfully installed Ubuntu Desktop 18.4 LTS.  This computer has no DVD and no wireless network card.

I believe I have found the proper drivers to load for the Netgear USB WiFi adapter (A6100 AC600) which I have acquired.  However, with no direct internet connection yet, I don’t know how to acquire and install those drivers.

There is internet access through an old iMac.

How can I do the equivalent of a “git clone” on that Mac, move the drivers to a USB, and then install those drivers on the Dell?